# OP-AMP Output Voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier, photodiode

In the below schematic,

[image: OP-AMP]

Photodiode is used ( not diode)

OP-AMP [OPA 380](http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/opa380.pdf)

So, Vo = If X Rf

**Case1:**

IPh= A , Rf= 10K, **VCC pin =5V**

Vout = A X Rf = A(10K)

**Case2:**

IPh= A , Rf= 10K, **VCC pin =3V**

Vout = A X Rf = A(10K)

Does it means, Vout will be irrespective of VCC voltage?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the output voltage of your amplifier is independent of the power supply voltage, *as long as that power voltage is large enough*.  Of course it can't be so large as to blow up the opamp either.

Note that the direction of the photocell current of the diode is down in this instance.  That means the current flows right to left thru the resistor, and the right end of the resistor will therefore be at higher voltage than the left end.  Due to the closed loop feedback, the opamp will make its output whatever it takes so that its negative input matches its positive input, which is ground.  The output will therefore swing from ground (0 V) at no light to some maximum a full light.  The power supply range must include that, plus whatever headroom the opamp needs to operate correctly.

If this is a "rail to rail" input and output opamp, then the negative output of the supply can be connected to ground, and the positive needs to be at least whatever the maximum output voltage will be due to the brightest light.

Comment: Note that, for the OPA380, the output will only go to about 0.1 volts for no light. However, it will go to zero if you load the output with 2k to -5 volts. See Figure 5 of the data sheet.

Comment: Output will be 0 to +ve .. right?

Comment: No, output will be 0 wrt ground.

Comment: I mean range will be 0 to +ve for different photodiode current.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it means, Vout will be irrespective of VCC voltage?

It totally means that and happy xmas.

You have the formulas that pretty much define what this circuit do all the way up to tens of kHz. Op-amps try to force the voltage at the inverting input to be the same as the voltage at the non-inverting input by using the feedback resistor (negative feedback).

As the non-inverting input is at 0V, the op-amp's output "changes" to ensure that the inverting input is at 0V also. In the simple case when the photodiode current is zero clearly, the output of the op-amp satisfies itself by producing 0V on the output.

If the input current is (say) -1uA (current into the photodiode), to prevent the inverting input going below 0V, the op-amp "sources" the 1uA from its output thru Rf and thus, the output voltage is now 1uA x Rf or put more generally: -

\$V_{out} = R_F\cdot I_{photodiode}\$

Given that the photodiode current is always travelling away from the op-amp we don't need to use a negative sign in the formula. This circuit will also work with a single rail op-amp providing the photodiode is connected the way shown - the output voltage will always be positive for any given photodiode current.

However, the type of op-amp used needs to be able to swing its inputs and outputs close to ground. Also you can't expect the output voltage to be greater than the op-amp supply voltage and it's usually the case that the highest output voltage will be a volt or so below the positive power rail (unless you use a rail-to-rail op-amp then it will get to within about 50 mV of the rail).

You might also be interested in quite a useful [**tool**](http://www.analog.com/designtools/en/photodiode/) provided by ADI: -

[image]

I've used it several times and you can pick different op-amps and choose various gain settings. It gives good results in terms of noise and offsets too. Try the AD8065 for starters - it's pretty awesome for low/medium frequency applications.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, independent, at least until you run out of headroom.

The OPA380 will drive its output to within about 500-600mV (the exact number depending the temperature, output loading and the particular op-amp sample- read the datasheet) of the positive rail, so if the input current exceeds (Vcc-600mV)/10K in magnitude the op-amp output may saturate near the positive rail.